# pixels for uploading photos to web

Tags: photo-editing, troubleshooting

i am currently using picasa 3 for editing my photos and uploading them to ebay.  ebay currently tells me that the pix need to be 500 pixels on the longest side and that i can't use the ones i have.  i have tried changing the dimensions to upload the photo, but i still keep getting the same message.  i have tried changing it to 800 x 1024 and various other dimensions available but none work and i don't know what i am doing.  can you help me?

Comment: What is the original resolution of the photos?

Comment: Both 800 and 1024 are more than 500. You need to scale it down even more.

Comment: @stativ - I thought 500 was a MINIMUM ?

Comment: I understand 500 px on the longest side as maximum 500 px. It doesn't make sense to me require 500 px on the longest side as minimum, because then the image of 1x600 px would still fullfill the requirement. Maybe the @Pat Benton can elaborate what is the error exactly.

Comment: @Digital Lightcraft – you are right, quick google says: Minimum Image Size: 500 x 500 pixels. Maximum Image Size: 9000 x 9000 pixels

Comment: You need to tell us how you are 'changing' the dimensions & if you have checked that method is working as you anticipate, ie, open in another app & check dimensions. Right now we have little to go on.

Comment: I strongly suspect this is a situation where you actually need someone in person to give you a helping hand. Grab a friend or family member who is familiar with digital imaging, and I'm sure this will be solved in no time. Do come back and post your solution as an answer if appropriate.

Comment: Are you sure the *file format* is one accepted by eBay? (Also: vote to close as off-topic.)

Answer (score 1):

Edited.

Reading some eBay documentation.

https://pages.ebay.co.uk/picture/guidelines.html and https://www.ebay.com/sellercenter/listings/photo-tips

> need to be 500 pixels on the longest side

It is **recommended** that the image has **at least** 500px on the longest side. But it can have more.

These websites automatically resize and recompress larger images.

So in theory, your image of 800x1024px should work. If it still does not work, it would be useful if you post a screen capture of the error message.

E-commerce websites like eBay prefer square images, so, consider cropping them into a square. The space available for the main image is 500x500px.

[image]

The higher resolution image will be used when you zoom in on the image.

[image]

A smaller image of 223x223px for the general listing will also be created.

[image]

Comment: eBay does not "prefer" square images - why do you claim so? Speaking of eBay in particular, the goal is to show large, detailed images to potential buyers. It would be an idiotic decision on eBay's part to insist that all images are 500x500 in size.

Comment: The main image, before the zooming, IS 500x500px.

Comment: And I claim so because there is a really clear, squared square around the images. Not only on eBay, but in a lot of other eStores.

Comment: And please read carefully before commenting that I claim all images are 500x500. I wrote even before the edition that they have higher resolution images when zooming.

Comment: Honestly, I think this is a terrible answer. I am restraining myself from downvoting. eBay is designed for the masses, not for pixel-pushers. Best is to upload one large version of each image of the item you want to include, and just let eBay do whatever resizing it does. You do not need to upload a 500x500 image for the item page.

Comment: Buying and a elling is the purpose of eBay.  Hence buying and selling is the purpose of the pictures on eBay. The advice to consider square is advice to spend time doing  something that won’t improve buying and selling. Furthermore it is unsupported by eBay documentation.

Comment: "The advice to consider square is advice to spend time doing something that won’t improve buying and selling." I'm not entirely sure about that. eBay's current policy with non-square images is to add white bars either at bottom and top or left and right in product listings. This means less space is actually available to show what you're selling.

Answer (score 1):

I think Rafael's answer has a very high probability of fully resolving the current issue with eBay.

What I'm addressing is similar issues of poor instructions on photo upload size you might encounter across the web (even on eBay when they change their requirements).

A site says something frustratingly vague like "Photo Size 500 pixels." You've tried a couple of images and both failed. The time has come for systematic "[Proof by Exhaustion](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_exhaustion)."

Our variables:

- Long side
- Short side
- Equals
- More than
- Less than

Start with squares, to simplify things. Make 3 test squares. 450 pixels on a side, 500 pixels on a side, and 550 pixels on a side. Try to upload all 3. Screenshot all errors. If all 3 error, it's time to suffer the joys of tech support hell, but at least you've got the screenshots to show there's a real problem.

Otherwise, you should now know if the image must be:
Less than 500 on at least one side.
Less than or equal to 500 on at least one side.
Exactly 500 on at least one side.
More than 500 on at least one side.
More than or equal to 500 on at least one side.

Based on which of these 5 possibilities you get, you can continue testing while keeping height fixed and varying width plus and minus 50 pixels (2 more test images), and keeping width fixed and and varying height plus and minus 50 pixels (2 more test images).

It sounds like a lot of work, but you should be able to get a good idea of how the initial requirement should have been phrased while only needing to make 7 test images.

Yes there may still be some unstated additional min/max, but for now we're just trying to find out the basic instructions to get started uploading anything.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I use Irfanview (32bit and 64bit) I find this very easy to use for resizing and it is a very powerful program should you want or need it.It is a free download.